# Is there function in Python which serves as main in C

Tags: python

I want to know whether there is a main function in Python as in C, etc. ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.  Typically,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    argc = len(sys.argv)
    argv = sys.argv
```

is the closest thing you get to a `main` in Python.  More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#Python).

Comment: (the conditional ensures the code inside it is only run when the file is run directly and not as a result of a library import or such)

Comment: @pst, I'm a little curious about the value of __name__ when it is running as a library call.

Comment: @Thomson Tan "The name of the module" (which is the filename, without directory information or ".py" extension). Hopefully the filename is not "__main__.py" :-) Because a file *represents a module* and a module *is an object* in Python: `import math; print math.__name__` should result in the same as `print __name__` *from within* the math module.

Answer (score 10):

No. Python scripts are executed from beginning to end, which means that there is no need for a `main()` function.

Having said that, many scripts use a **main sentinel**, which checks the value of a certain global to see if the script/module is being run directly:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  dosomething()
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is executed from top to down like a script. There is no main function. However, when you want to define as certain execution structure, you can choose to check if the magic attribute `__name__` is set to `__main__`, which it does only when it is executed directly through an interpretor (that is not imported as module).

There are some ways of defining the `__name__ == '__main__'` construct. [This article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829) gives some pointers.